# Semi tower of hanoi

Tags: c++, c++14

```cpp
void semiHanoi(int n, char source, char destination, char temp) {
    if (n == 2) {//base case
        cout << "Move from " << source << " to " << destination << endl;
        cout << "Move from " << temp << " to " << destination << endl;
    }
    else {
        semiHanoi((n - 1), source, destination, temp);//to make moves
        semiHanoi(2, destination, temp, source);
        //semiHanoi(2 * (n - 1), destination, source, temp);

    }
}
```

I am tried a lot but could not figure out what and how the recursive calls should go!
Please Help

**This is the question:**
Semi-Hanoi is a problem very similar to Hanoi problem. The only difference is that your input in semi-Hanoi must be an even number of disks like 2n and they are set as shown in the following figure-a. The peg A has all the even numbered disks such as 2,4,6, … and the peg B has the rest (all the odd numbered disks such as 1,3,5,...). the rules of movement in semi-Hanoi is the same as Hanoi’s rules: • only one disk can be moved at a time • a bigger disk cannot be placed on top of a smaller one The goal is to move all the disks on the peg C in order as shown in figure-b
here is the image how disks initially looks like

[image]

Comment: Please specify your problem... do you have trouble finding the right algorithmic approach or do you know what you would do by hand and have trouble implementing it?

Comment: It should be possible to use the same algorithm to solve this as traditional TOH. The only issue is that in the traditional solution it is easy to predict which of the two empty columns should be used to make the first move to, to ensure that the last move ends up at the target. In this case the choice is A->C then B->C or just B->A as the opening move. Otherwise, please enjoy solving your homework :-)